# SQL Server Numeric with different precision

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the difference between `numeric(30,10)` and `numeric(20,10)` in sql server and why is that
`3.456/2.8` gives result as `1.2342857100` in first case and `1.2342857143` in second case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`numeric(30,10)` is a `numeric` with a precision of 30, and a scale of 10, where as the latter has a precision of 20 and a scale of 10. For the former, this means the value can contain *up* to 30 digits, with 10 of those after the decimal point. The latter up to 20 digits, with 10 of those after the decimal point.

As for why they give different values, that's all explained in [Precision, scale, and Length (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), where the resulting scale and precision is calculated as below:

> | Operation | Result precision | Result scale * |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | e1 + e2 | max(s1, s2) + max(p1-s1, p2-s2) + 1 | max(s1, s2) |
> | e1 - e2 | max(s1, s2) + max(p1-s1, p2-s2) + 1 | max(s1, s2) |
> | e1 * e2 | p1 + p2 + 1 | s1 + s2 |
> | e1 / e2 | p1 - s1 + s2 + max(6, s1 + p2 + 1) | max(6, s1 + p2 + 1) |
> | e1 { UNION / EXCEPT / INTERSECT } e2 | max(s1, s2) + max(p1-s1, p2-s2) | max(s1, s2) |
> | e1 % e2 | min(p1-s1, p2 -s2) + max( s1,s2 ) | max(s1, s2) |
>
> * The result precision and scale have an absolute maximum of 38. When a result precision is greater than 38, it's reduced to 38, and the corresponding scale is reduced to try to prevent truncating the integral part of a result. In some cases such as multiplication or division, scale factor won't be reduced, to maintain decimal

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server has very detailed rules on how scale and precision are affected by arithmetic operators, documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).  For addition and subtraction, it is pretty simple.

For division, the logic is . . . rather more convoluted.

The reason is because the precision is set by this formula:  `p1 - s1 + s2 + max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)`.  To be honest, I don't know how they came across this formula, but it is why the precision is what it is.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that you defined a  column as  `numeric(30,10)` which means a precision p of 30 and a scale s of 10.

This is the logic behind : p1 - s1 + s2 + max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)